# How to implement httpAuth in cucumber step definition

Tags: cucumber, e2e-testing, http-authentication, testcafe

There is a way to handle httpAuth in testCafe, http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/http-authentication.html ,
I am trying to test a site which first I have to go through httpAuth. The mentioned function is for fixture. How I should handle httpAuth inside a cucumber step definition? An example much appreciated.

My stepdef is similar to

Given('The page is loaded', async function () {
await testController.navigateTo('http://example.com').httpAuth({
username: 'logmein',
password: 'test123'
})
});

And I am getting

TypeError: testController.navigateTo(...).httpAuth is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test.httpAuth` of `fixture.httpAuth` methods are intended to specify the credentials to be used by an individual test or a fixture, so these methods should be used in the context of `test` or `fixture`, but not in the context of `testController`.
You cannot use `httpAuth` inside a test body.
Please see the example from documentation (https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/authentication.html#http-authentication):

```
fixture `My fixture`
    .page `http://example.com`
    .httpAuth({
        username: 'username',
        password: 'Pa$$word',

        // Optional parameters, can be required for the NTLM authentication.
        domain:      'CORP-DOMAIN',
        workstation: 'machine-win10'
    });

test('Test1', async t => {});          // Logs in as username

test                                   // Logs in as differentUserName
    .httpAuth({
        username: 'differentUserName',
        password: 'differentPa$$word'
    })
    ('Test2', async t => {});
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex, For the details. I tried the example and it works fine. But is there any way to handle this HTTP authentication inside the step definition?

Comment: No, I think if you want to access different protected pages, it's better to separate your test in parts.